# How to use setTextColor for Android Radio Buttons?

Tags: android, radio-button, textcolor

I am trying to change the text color of a RadioButton (which is 
defined in an xml layout and is in a RadioGroup) on selecting it.

When I change the text color directly in the Eclipse Android Layout 
Editor by setting the TextColor property to "@color/red" (which I 
defined in strings.xml), it works just fine, but when I try to do this 
programmatically during runtime as

```
myRadioButton.setTextColor(R.color.red);
```

it only turns the color to grey, not to red as intended.

R.color.red (@color/red) is correctly defined as a hex value 
("#FF0000"), but it does turn the text color to red in the 
layout editor, but not via a Java command.

Comment: use `getResources().getColor(R.color.red)` instead of `R.color.red`

Comment: Thank you for the answer..but when using this and unselecting the button the color does not go back to the default color. How can I achieve this?

Comment: try to change in `onCheckedChanged()` to default color?

Comment: Had to customize a bit but it works now..thank you so much!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

if your color.xml is like:

```
<color name="errorColor">#f00</color>
```

and then use this code to show it:

```
myRadioButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
```

Comment: Just a heads up, getColor() has been deprecated in API 23, and now we have ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);

Answer (score 4):

there are some other ways to do so

```
myRadioButton.setTextColor(Color.RED);
or
myRadioButton.setTextColor(Color.rgb(red, green, blue)); 
// where red green and blue are the int values
```

edited if you want to get from resources then use
getResources().getColor(R.color.red) ;